# Spring Boot's JHipster WAR Artifact Renamed to JAR Won't Run

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jhipster

I've created an empty, monolithic JHipster project.

After building a JHipster project, an executable WAR file is created automatically. After renaming this file to JAR, the application won't run as expected anymore.

```
jhipster-apps/foobar/target   ✗                                                                                                                                           1d ⚑
▶ ls -l
total 216096
-rw-r--r--    1 brborges  staff       431 27 Aug 12:29 Dockerfile
drwxr-xr-x  105 brborges  staff      3360 27 Aug 12:29 cache-loader
drwxr-xr-x    9 brborges  staff       288 27 Aug 12:29 classes
-rw-r--r--    1 brborges  staff       188 27 Aug 12:29 entrypoint.sh
drwxr-xr-x   10 brborges  staff       320 27 Aug 12:30 foobar-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT
-rwxr--r--    1 brborges  staff  58688877 27 Aug 12:30 foobar-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.war
-rw-r--r--    1 brborges  staff  51095430 27 Aug 12:30 foobar-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.war.original
drwxr-xr-x    3 brborges  staff        96 27 Aug 12:29 generated-sources
drwxr-xr-x    3 brborges  staff        96 27 Aug 12:33 generated-test-sources
drwxr-xr-x    3 brborges  staff        96 27 Aug 12:30 maven-archiver
drwxr-xr-x    3 brborges  staff        96 27 Aug 12:29 maven-status
drwxr-xr-x   32 brborges  staff      1024 27 Aug 12:30 surefire-reports
drwxr-xr-x    7 brborges  staff       224 27 Aug 12:29 test-classes
drwxr-xr-x    3 brborges  staff        96 27 Aug 12:30 test-results
drwxr-xr-x    9 brborges  staff       288 27 Aug 12:29 www

jhipster-apps/foobar/target   ✗                                                                                                                                           1d ⚑
▶ cp foobar-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.war foobar-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

jhipster-apps/foobar/target   ✗                                                                                                                                           1d ⚑
▶ diff foobar-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.war foobar-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

jhipster-apps/foobar/target   ✗                                                                                                                                           1d ⚑
▶ echo $?
0
```

Executing the WAR file:

```
jhipster-apps/foobar/target   ✗                                                                                                                                          1d ⚑  ⍉
▶ java -jar foobar-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.war &
[1] 18713
▶ curl -I http://localhost:8080
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Pragma: no-cache
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Mon, 27 Aug 2018 19:51:08 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Mon, 27 Aug 2018 19:30:48 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Length: 992
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en-CA
```

Executing the copied JAR file:

```
jhipster-apps/foobar/target   ✗                                                                                                                                          1d ⚑  ⍉
▶ java -jar foobar-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar &
[1] 18783
▶ curl -I http://localhost:8080
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Mon, 27 Aug 2018 19:54:56 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

We need the file to have a JAR extension due to other tools that have been designed to run Java SE applications with this type of file.

While I understand the WAR is executable, the file type "WAR" has always been designed to be deployed on Servlet containers or application servers, and not to be  executed with `java -jar`. For this, tools expect files to be of type JAR.

Comment: Thats strange, but this used to work(both war and jar) and personally I was always using Docker or Gradle to run the apps so never checked this recently. Not sure if something changed after Spring boot 2, may be it would be nice to check the behaviour for a basic spring boot jar as well.

Comment: Changing <packaging> to jar will create a JAR file that does not work as expected either.

Comment: I think when you generate jar it doesn't package the static assets required for front end

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change the `<packaging>` section in your `pom.xml` from `war` to `jar` if you want to create an JAR file rather than a WAR. You'll also need to move the contents of `src/main/webapp` to a `src/main/static` (or another [supported location](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-convert-an-existing-application-to-spring-boot))

Although you can run a Spring Boot WAR file using `java -jar myApp.war`, the internal structure is not the same as an executable JAR. The WAR file contains a few limited classes in the root (under the `org.springframework.boot.loader` package) that provide just enough code to launch the web server and bootstrap itself. The web server will then consider `WEB-INF/lib` and `WEB-INF/classes`.

With an executable JAR file, the folders considered are `BOOT-INF/lib` and `BOOT-INF/classes`.

It's possible that renaming might have worked in the past by accident, but it was never a recommended approach.

Answer (score 1):

Packaging type alone won't work. As Phil pointed out we use `src/main/webapp` folder for our client-side assets this is built by webpack into the `target/www` folder.

So after changing package type in pom, you also need to modify pom to copy the generated static assets from `target/www` folder to the `src/resources/static` folder.